# request.path is undefined in node 10

Tags: node.js, http

Per the [node docs, `request.path` should exist](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_path), however it doesn't on node `v10.13.0`

```
const  http = require('http')

require('../src/shared/globals.js')

const port = 4000

const host = '127.0.0.1'

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  log(`>>>> url ${request.url}`)
  log(`>>>> path ${request.path}`)
})

module.exports = async function() {
  server.listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log(`Web hook server listening at http://${host}:${port}`)
  })
}
```

Will return:

```
  >>>> url /
  >>>> path undefined
```

Why is request.path undefined?

Comment: You did test this in other versions to prove this wasn't a version problem, right? the way you word your question, it's almost as if you're saying it's a problem specific to that node version, but that's highly unlikely.

Comment: @KevinB No, I did not backtest the issue. I did not not say or hint that it was a version problem, I'm including the version number because that's good practice - for example, maybe the docs don't apply to node 10. Are you downmodding the question because I didn't backtest it?

Answer (score 2):

It is included in the doc but it is under the section "ClientRequest".  My understanding is that it is used when you want to call the server. It is undefined because the 'request' in the callback is not a ClientRequest.

You can use the url module to parse the 'request.url' that you are getting.  Here is an example https://www.codexpedia.com/node-js/node-js-http-request-url-param-path-and-body/

Edit:  Here are some helpfull link.

Node.js `url.parse()` link: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

Node.js Client Request Doc: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Node.js `request.path` Doc: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_path

Comment: Thanks @Plpicard. If you add a link to the docs for the `request` given to `http.createServer` I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a link to `request` given to `http.createServer` - *not* clientRequest which as you mention is irrelevant.

Comment: The answer the OP was looking for is that the `request` argument is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage` https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Comment: That's confusing that all docs call it "request", but it isn't a `ClientRequest`, it is an `IncomingMessage`.